# Can I use another shortcut for auto import in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

The shortcut `Alt+Enter` is intercepted by my window manager(i3) to create a new terminal, so the default shortcut of `auto import`(which is also `Alt + Enter`) doesn't work in pycharm. Can I use another shortcut to do the `auto import`? It's really a pain to import the required package manually every time.

Comment: You can re-map your keys. Did you try that? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to

```
File > Settings > Keymap
```

And remap your auto-import to a different key or combination of keys. The keymap should be labeled under

```
Other > Show Intention Actions
```

You can search for it in the search bar.
Google is your friend and can come in handy when asking simple questions like these, so please abstain from asking questions that can be easily found online.

Comment: Thank you. I did search for a long time online, and I've looked into `Keymap` window before, but I didn't find the answer because I was looking for the keyword `import` on that window, so I thought that maybe I couldn't change the shortcut there. The action turns out to be called `Show Intention Actions`, I didn't see that coming. Thanks a lot. It works. :)